# How can I animate a child view in a recyclerView element after notifyItemChange() in onBindViewHolder()

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I want to animate a `textView` inside a `recyclerView` to transition upwards when I call `notifyItemChanged(position)`. This is my `onBindViewholder()` that is being called automatically when a change in the adapter occurs:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (unfoldedIndexes.contains(position)) { // if already unfolded
        bindUnfoldedState(holder, holder.getLayoutPosition());
    }else{ // show the folded state}
}

public void bindUnfoldedState(ViewHolder holder, int position){


    if(lc.isBtnEnabled()){
            holder.Price.setText("text");
            holder.Price.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(500);
            holder.Price.animate().translationY(-38).setDuration(500);
            holder.checkText.animate().translationY(38).setDuration(500);
        }else {
            holder.Price.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(500);
            holder.Price.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(500);
            holder.checkText.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(500);
        }

}
```

my `notifyItemChanged()` is being called from a `fragment` `onClick` like so:

```
 ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            // some changes to the data
            adapter.getLcns().get(Position).setBtnEnabled(true);
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(Position);
            }
}
```

`isBtnEnabled()` is true if s`etBtnEnabled(true)` is called.

The problem is that the animation is not happening. With logs I can confirm that `onBindViewHolder()` is being called and the animation should appear but it is not happening.

I was using anormal `listView` before I converted to a `recyclerView` and the animations were working in on `getView()`

Comment: Can you share a video/gif with current behavior?

Comment: You should use a payload on onBindViewHolder

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Adapter.notifyItemChanged(position, payload)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object)) to deploy an update to already visible ViewHolders:

OnClick:

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // some changes to the data
        adapter.getLcns().get(Position).setBtnEnabled(true);
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(Position, true);   // "true" is the payload
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
    if(payloads != null && !payloads.isEmpty()){  // update payloads, partial rebind
        Object lastPayload = payloads.get(payloads.size -1)); // in this case only last payload is meaningful
        if(lastPayload instanceof Boolean)
            bindUnfoldedState(holder, lastPayload);
    }else
        onBindViewHolder(holder, position);   // regular binding of item
}

public void bindUnfoldedState(ViewHolder holder, boolean unfold){
     if(unfold){ ... } 
     else { ... }
}

// you should also consider adding this override to prevent animation leaking when viewholder
// is recycled and reused for another position:
@Override
public void onViewRecycled(ViewHolder holder){
    holder.Price.animate().cancel();
    holder.checkText.animate().cancel();
}
```

Comment: this is not making sense to me. why did you put `if(unfold)` in `bindUnfoldedState`? this method already assumes an unfolded state. I dont understand why you pass the `bool` value

Comment: @user7331538 it's to show how you can consume the payload. You didn't post other methods from your adapter so I was partially guessing. Of course you can instead have a switch inside `onBindViewHolder` that will check `lastPayload` and call `bindUnfoldedState`/`bindFoldedState` based on its value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to invoke `setHasStableIds(true)` in the adapter constructor. It is much easier to animate in `onBindViewHolder` when ids are stable.

Comment: I already have this. Not in the constructor but after I initialize the adapter `adapter.setHasStableIds(true)`

Answer (score 0):

`notifyItemChange()` without payload will force the item to redraw whereas you want to animate existing `View`. The idea is to get the `View` from `RecyclerView` and then perform the animation directly onto it. e.g.

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Adapter.ViewHolder holder = (Adapter.ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(Position);
                adapter.getLcns().get(Position).setBtnEnabled(true);
                if (holder != null){
                    holder.Price.setText("text");
                    holder.Price.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(500);
                    holder.Price.animate().translationY(-38).setDuration(500);
                    holder.checkText.animate().translationY(38).setDuration(500);
                }
            }
        });
```

Note the line

```
Adapter.ViewHolder holder = (Adapter.ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(Position);
```

here the `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition` is returning the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` which you need to typecast into your ViewHolder

or

use the [nofityItemChanged with payload](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyitemchanged):

from the docs

> Client can optionally pass a payload for partial change. These
>   payloads will be merged and may be passed to adapter's
>   onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int, List) if the item is already
>   represented by a ViewHolder and it will be rebound to the same
>   ViewHolder

Comment: I think this might work. Quick question: `Adapter.ViewHolder` comes from `android.widget` or `androidx.recyclerview.widget`?

Comment: Thats your ViewHolder class that contains the Price and checkText

Comment: This still does not work. I enter the block `if(holder != null){}` but it is like the UI is not updating with the animation because internally, the setText() is happening its just not showing on UI (including animations).

Comment: @user7331538 can you share your project at sahil.manchanda2@gmail.com so that i can take a look at

Answer (score 0):

You can set a global flag(say boolean) in Adapter, make the boolean false when Adapter is called first time, and make a public method which set the flag true and notifies at that position.

The code may look like this

```
private boolean animation=false;

    public notifyAtPosition(int position){
       animation=true;
       notifyItemChanged(position);
     }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (unfoldedIndexes.contains(position)) { // if already unfolded
        bindUnfoldedState(holder, holder.getLayoutPosition());
    }else{ // show the folded state}
}

public void bindUnfoldedState(ViewHolder holder, int position){


    if(animation){
            holder.Price.setText("text");
            holder.Price.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(500);
            holder.Price.animate().translationY(-38).setDuration(500);
            holder.checkText.animate().translationY(38).setDuration(500);
        }else {
            holder.Price.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(500);
            holder.Price.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(500);
            holder.checkText.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(500);
        }

}
```

Hope, you got the answer.

Comment: not helpful. How is this different than what my if statement achieves?

Comment: Did you try the way I suggested?

Comment: no it did not work. It has to do with the UI not updating. when I switch apps on device, and then switch back, I see the final results of the animation. It is like when I swtich back to this app, android triggers a UI update and the animation is done. That is the problem.